# Wordpress - show Bio in author.php only for Editor role

Tags: wordpress, roles, author

I have an `author.php` page that must look differently according to post author's role. If it's role is *Editor* or *Admin*, the bios is shown. Otherwise (for Author, for example), it is not. But I can't find it anywhere. I had a clue to use `get_userdata`, but couldn't manage to do so.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `$wp_query` global to get the author's role:

```
global $wp_query;
$roles = $wp_query->queried_object->roles;
if( $roles[0] == 'editor' ) {
    // do stuff
}
```