# wp favorites get user total favorite posts issue

Tags: plugins, wordpress, buddypress

im trying to get the user total favorite post but i doesn't seem to work im using 
buddypress and im establishing in each profile user have their favorite box which any article they like and set it to their fav it will show up in their profile so basically im trying to make it work but its not working.

i go visit a my profile and it shows up fine but i visit someone's else and mine shows up it doesn't show his favorite posts just mine its like its looping only mine but i logged in using another user and its happening the same issue his favorite posts show up in my profile and in his profile im using wp favorites plugin by the way.

so heres what im trying to make work but it shows fine in my profile but once i
visit other profiles it shows the exact same thing it wont show their favorite posts instead of mine

here is what im trying to make work http://pastie.org/7697956

`

```
<div class="profile-box items-following">

    <h3><?php _e('fav posts', 'bd_lang'); ?></h3>

    <div class="profile-content">

        <?php $favorite_post_ids = wpfp_get_users_favorites(user_id);
        if($favorite_post_ids) { ?>

                <?php foreach ($favorite_post_ids as $o) : $p = get_post($o); if ($p->post_status == 'publish') { ?>    

                    <div class="profile-item">

                        <!--Begin Image-->
                        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail($o)) { ?>                   
                            <div class="post-thumbnail">
                                <a href="<?php get_permalink($o); ?>" title="<?php echo $p->post_title; ?>">
                                    <?php $image = bd_resize(get_post_thumbnail_id($o), '', 50, 0, true); ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo $image[url]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image[width]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image[height]; ?>" alt="<?php if(get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id($o), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true)) { echo get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id($o), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); } else { echo $p->post_title; } ?>" />       
                                </a>                
                            </div>                  
                        <?php } ?>
                        <!--End Image-->

                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($o); ?>" title="<?php echo $p->post_title; ?>"><?php echo $p->post_title; ?></a>

                    </div>

                <?php } endforeach; ?>

        <?php } else { ?>

            <div class="profile-item">
                <strong><?php _e('No posts have been added yet.', 'bd_lang'); ?></strong>
            </div>

        <?php } ?>

    </div>

</div> `
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$user_id` variable should contain the ID of the user queried. Take a look at e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16122901/1981996) on how to get author info from the `$wp_query` global.

Comment: Well yeah i know that but i dont want to get all posts by only one user id so basiclly i place the above code i posted in the profile.php under buddypress  but i want it to get each user automaticlly their posts favorites not only a user id what happends i can only see my user gets favorite posts but i visit someone else profile i see my posts it should be their posts also you get me ?.. I hope im making my self clear, i need some help im not a wp & php expert just know my basics im not verly knowlageble i would appriciated alot if you could help me out, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
wpfp_get_users_favorites( bp_displayed_user_id() );
```

Comment: thanks but i tried it not working heres how i implemented it http://pastie.org/7699589 im pulling my brains out cant seem to make it work it displays fine in my profile but other users profiles my fav posts shows up instead it should be their posts

Comment: also tried this way and it gave me "no posts have been found" `<?php $favorite_post_ids = wpfp_get_users_favorites( bp_displayed_user_id() ); if($favorite_post_ids) { ?>` so not working

Comment: in other words im trying to get ID of the currently viewed page's user if that explains more depth of what im trying to do

Comment: Just echo out bp_displayed_user_id()  and see it the value is correct. If it is incorrect, you're injecting the markup wrongly. And where does this code live? In the single/profile-loop.php template file? If not, look at the do_action calls in that file.

Comment: thanks, for trying i appreciated i tried that heres a http://pastie.org/7700029 the both i tried and still nothing...

Comment: Then you aren't in the single/profile-loop when you call bp_displayed_user_id(), so it won't matter what you try. You have a basic injection error.

Comment: well im inside the single/profile-loop.php im adding my favorite post box in their and nope not working either way

Comment: here's several attempts i tried and dont work its from profile-loop.php 1.http://pastie.org/7700397 2.http://pastie.org/7700401 3.http://pastie.org/7700407 if you could check whats wrong im pulling my brains out cant seem to make it work i been at this for hours...

Answer (score 0):

I"m also using this plugin, but mostly to list my own favorites as thumbnails.
I only get an error at the "foreach" statement, but other than that it works.

I don't know if it will help you, but here it is anyway:

```
<?php $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author)); ?>

<?php $user_favs = wpfp_get_users_favorites($curauth->display_name); ?>
<ul>


<?php  
foreach ($user_favs as $user_fav)
  {
echo "<a href='".get_permalink($user_fav)."' title='". get_the_title($user_fav) ."'>" . get_the_post_thumbnail( $user_fav, array(335,335) ) . "</a>";
  } ; ?>
```

Comment: im not encountering any error myself im just trying to get each users favorite posts on their profiles/buddypress instead i get a looping of my favorite posts on their profile so that's my issue

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the ID of the current author page and not of the current user viewing the author page, you can use this method:

```
      $curauth = (get_query_var('author_name')) ? get_user_by('slug', get_query_var('author_name')) : get_userdata(get_query_var('author'));
```

This creates an object which you can use to get what you want.

For example, curauth->ID holds the ID of that author.

For this to work you need to put this code and any relevant code in the author.php template file. I assume you already do that.

P.S. It's all described very well in the Wordpress Codex.